# count how many times a conditional event occurs

Tags: mql4

I'm trying to count how many times a conditional event occurs.
But when I test it, it gives me unrealistic numbers.
I don't think I am coding it correctly anybody want to help me out??

```
    for(i=0;i<Bars; i++)

{

//Condition I want met

if(Close[i+1]<Close[i+2]<Close[i+3]<Close[i+4]<Close[i+5]);

//Add 1 each time condition is met for sum total when the for loop ends

x=x+1;

Comment(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the ; of the if statement effectively terminates the conditional statements (so the x=x+1 will not be executed correctly according to the condition(s).

Hence , please change

```
if(Close[i+1]<Close[i+2]<Close[i+3]<Close[i+4]<Close[i+5]);

//Add 1 each time condition is met for sum total when the for loop ends

x=x+1;
```

to

```
if(Close[i+1]<Close[i+2]<Close[i+3]<Close[i+4]<Close[i+5])
{
//Add 1 each time condition is met for sum total when the for loop ends
x=x+1;}
```